# Add non-flex switch to existing switch stack

Tags: cisco, switch

I have an existing stack consisting of two CISCO 2960-S series switches. They are connected using the flex-stacking cables in the back, the top one being the master and the lower being the slave.

I have a 3rd switch, slightly different model, just a plain 2960 series that I'd like to add to the existing stack as a slave. It does not have a flex stacking option/does not have those cables in the back.

So my question is straight forward. Can I still add this switch as a slave? If so, are there any diagrams or guides to help out? I'm unfamiliar with which ports should be connected where and what commands may need to be run.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

> Can I still add this switch as a slave?

No. It cannot be added as a stack member as it does not have the required stack ports.